# Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n): nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2695: 24000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, stored-procedures, dbi

I have an R script that calls a stored procedure in SQL Server.  The Stored procedure in MS SQL Server inserts records from one table into another table that has an auto-increment ID column (`IDENTITY(1,1)`).  When the stored procedure executes, after inserting rows from one table into another, the auto-incremented ID (`id`) and the inserted value (`file_name`) are returned.  When I run procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, every executes as expected and a table is returned with `id` and `file_name`.  However, when I execute the stored procedure call in R using the `DBI` package, I get the following error:

```
Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n) :    
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2695: 24000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state Warning message: 
In dbClearResult(rs) : Result already cleared
```

Does anyone know how to remedy this problem?  I looked through dozens of other posts on SO and none seem to resolve this for me.

As background, here is a toy example of my two tables and a stored proc and my call in R Studio that demonstrate the issue for reproducibility.  I'm also using R Studio Version 1.3.1073 with R-4.0.2:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[etl_log](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [file_name] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
        [file_description] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[etl_log_temp](
    [File Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [File Description] [varchar](255) NULL) on [PRIMARY]
    GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_files_to_etl_log]
AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[etl_log]
           ([file_name] ,[file_description])
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.file_name
SELECT
       [File Name], [File Description]
FROM [dbo].[etl_log_temp]

GO
```

In R Studio, I'm calling:

```
files_succesfully_downloaded <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "exec [dbo].[insert_files_to_etl_log]")
```

My expected output into `files_succesfully_downloaded` should be a data frame that look something like this:

```
id      file_name
1       filex
2       filey
3       filez
```

Instead, I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Try adding "SET NOCOUNT ON;" as first statement in stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This did the trick.  Can you explain why this works?  If you want to include this as an official answer, I'll accept.

Comment: some libraries do not expect (or are not designed) to handle messages produced by tsql. By default it is set off and the client receives a "message" about the number of rows affected. This message confuses some interfaces. Turning nocount on suppresses the message and avoids the "confusion". There are also other considerations you can read about by simply searching for that statement.